# Doctrine MappingException on ManyToOne relationship

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, nette

I'm struggling with creation of `ManyToOne` relationship between two entities. According to documentation, this my code should be enough to create valid ManyToOne relationship, but I keep getting error described below. I must be missing something obvious, but I'm not sure what it is.

Project has many RemoteVotes.

The error that application throws is:

```
Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException
The target-entity App\Model\RemoteVote cannot be found in 'App\Model\Project#remoteVotes'.
```

Relevant part of RemoteVote.php model:

```
   namespace App\Model;

   /**
    * @ORM\Entity
    * @ORM\Table(name="remote_votes")
    */
    class RemoteVote extends BaseEntity {

    ...

   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project", inversedBy="remoteVotes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $project;

   ...
```

Relevant bit of Project.php model:

```
namespace App\Model;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="projects")
 */
class Project extends BaseEntity
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->remoteVotes = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    ...


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="RemoteVote", mappedBy="project", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $remoteVotes;

    ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, this wasn't Doctrine issue, but caching issue of the framework. Deleting cache solved it.